# Why there is an error saying 1:41: unexpected string constant whenever I start R?

Tags: r

Whenever I start the R, there is an error code like this.

Error: 1:41: unexpected string constant

2:         function(...){

3:         if(capabilities("

```
                                       ^
```

I appreciate your help in advance :)

Comment: How are you starting R? Does it happen when you type `R --vanilla` on the command line? Is it possible that you have broken code in an `.Rprofile` file? See `?Startup`.

Comment: @MikaelJagan Thank you so much! I had a broken code in an .Rprofile file. 

If someone has the same problem with me, type 
> file.edit('~/.Rprofile') and check whether there is a wrong initial condition.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.